# pandas datetime plotting issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I'm not sure what's going on here, but when I try to do a scatter plot with a dataframe that has the index set to datetimes, I get a much wider range of dates in the plot for the x-axis. Here's an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

datetimes = ['2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:05',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:10', '2020-01-01 01:00:15',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:20', '2020-01-01 01:00:25',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:30', '2020-01-01 01:00:35',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:40', '2020-01-01 01:00:45']
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(datetimes)
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = values
df = df.set_index(datetimes)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))
ax.scatter(df.index, df.values)
plt.show()
```

I get this:
[image: This does not plot correctly]

Yet if I do a plot instead of a scatter

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))
ax.plot(df)
plt.show()
```

I get:
[image: This plots correctly]

I don't understand why the x-axis has a huge date range on the scatter plot which is not included in the datetime range I gave it. It appears to work correctly using `plot` but not `scatter`. I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious here but I haven't had any success googling it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could not reproduce your chart with this code.

Comment: The scatter dots follow exactly the line -- from left bottom to right top -- in the charts I produced with your code.

Comment: The issue is the x-axis scale of the scatter plot. If you look at the line plot, the axis is only for the relevant hours. Make sure you're in matplotlib 3.3.1, or specify `xlim`.

Comment: Thanks! I really should have specified which version of matplotlib I'm using. I have matplotlib 3.0.3 so this is probably an issue with upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sligtly shortened your code to:

```
datetimes = ['2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:05',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:10', '2020-01-01 01:00:15',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:20', '2020-01-01 01:00:25',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:30', '2020-01-01 01:00:35',
             '2020-01-01 01:00:40', '2020-01-01 01:00:45']
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values}, index=pd.to_datetime(datetimes))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
ax.scatter(df.index, df['values'])
plt.show()
```

but it should not matter.

Another detail is that *df.values* retrieves the underlying *Numpy* array,
whereas *df['values']* (as I wrote) retrieves just the column of interest.

The plot I got is quite as expected:

[image]

Maybe it is a matter of the version of *Pandas* and/or *Pyplot*.
I use *Pandas* version *1.0.3* and *Pyplot* version *3.2.1*.
If you have older versions, maybe you should upgrade?

Another option: Set manually *x* axis limits:

```
plt.xlim(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01 00:59:55'),
    pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01 01:00:50'))
```

Comment: I've always used df.values and df['values'] interchangeably in the past and have no idea why I didn't realize they are different. That is super useful info. I'm using matplotlib 3.0.3 and pandas 1.0.3 so I will upgrade and see if that helps. I had some weird errors when using `set_xlim` if it was called before the plot call but moving it after the plot call fixed that. Thanks for the great info!

Comment: General suggestion: Don't use column names the same as existing *Pandas* attributes. They should differ at least in other case of letters. E.g. "values" is an attribute of a DataFrame, so use e.g. "Values" (upper case "V"). But a better solution is to use some other words, like "Val" or "Vals".

Answer (score 2):

your code runs just fine on my machine (matplotlib 3.2.2 and pandas 1.0.5). what version of matplotlib and pandas you're in?

try updating your libraries or use this:

```
ax.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
```

Comment: I'm using matplotlib 3.0.3 and pandas 1.0.3 so maybe upgrading will fix this. Thank you! I should have checked that but I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason without research but if you use  `plt.xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])` you can move on:
[image]

Comment: Yep, that was what I needed. I tried this but had it called right before the plot call and it gave me an odd error. I had previously used `ax.set_ylim()` before the plot call with no errors but for some reason I needed to move `ax.set_xlim()` to after the plot call. Thanks for the quick reply!